# NULL value not being detected

Tags: c

I can't seem to understand what is wrong here, can someone please help me out?
Every time the program runs, it outputs all the words of the sentence. It then tries to copy a 11th word (there is only 10), which it shouldn't since it should be detecting the NULL. My TA couldn't figure out what was wrong, so either he didn't try very hard or it's more complicated than i previously thought.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct myWord{
    char Word[21];
    int Length;
};

int main(){
    struct myWord WordList[21];
    char myString[] = "the cat in the hat jumped over the lazy fox";
    char* temp;
    int n = 0, i;

    temp = strtok(myString, " ");
    while (WordList[n].Word != NULL){
        printf("%s\n", temp);
        strcpy(WordList[n].Word, temp);
        temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
        WordList[n].Length = strlen(temp);
        n++;
    }
    printf("works!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should in fact, test if temp != NULL in your while loop. Plus, you should swap

```
    temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
    WordList[n].Length = strlen(temp);
```

with

```
    WordList[n].Length = strlen(temp);
    temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
```

if you want the correct length of the word

```
temp = strtok(myString, " ");
while (temp != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", temp);
    strcpy(WordList[n].Word, temp);
    WordList[n].Length = strlen(temp);
    temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
    n++;
}
```

Comment: Ah, you seem to have figured out the problem. The problem appeared to be the order in which i had everything placed, and when i swapped them around with your help it fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are checking `WordList[n].Word` against `NULL`, which is meaningless since it is uninitialized at that point. You are also setting `Length` to the next strings' length, since you rerun `strtok` before calling `strlen(temp)`. Try something like this:

```
temp = strtok(myString, " ");
while (temp != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", temp);
    strcpy(WordList[n].Word, temp);
    WordList[n].Length = strlen(WordList[n].Word);
    temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
    n++;
}
```

Also -- depending on the use of this code, beware buffer overflows. You should check that `n` doesn't exceed 21 (the number of `WordList` items you have), and that the length of `temp` doesn't exceed 21 (the space you have in each `struct myWord` for a `Word`). `strncpy` might help particularly for the latter. I'd probably also `#define` the max size for clarity:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 21

struct myWord {
    char Word[MAXLEN];
    int Length;
};

int main() {
    struct myWord WordList[MAXLEN];
    char myString[] = "the cat in the hat jumped over the lazy fox";
    char* temp;
    int n = 0;

    temp = strtok(myString, " ");
    while (n < MAXLEN && temp != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", temp);
        strncpy(WordList[n].Word, temp, MAXLEN);
        WordList[n].Word[MAXLEN - 1] = 0; // strncpy might not null terminate
        WordList[n].Length = strlen(WordList[n].Word);
        temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
        n++;
    }
    printf("works!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have tried it with temp, also to no avail, previously. I'll take a look at your other suggestions though, thanks.

Comment: actually WordList[n].Word is initialized at that point since it's an array of size 21 inside of another array of structs. So effectively it'll NEVER be NULL

Comment: It's inside `WordList`, an uninitialized stack variable, so its contents will depend on whatever garbage happened to be on the stack there. I also just tested the version of the code I posted, and it seems to work fine -- how are you determining that 11 words are detected?

Comment: I had a check inside of the while that would output the value of n, n starts at 0 and when the loop would try to run on the 11th time, it would output the check "11th" or something, and then crash.